# How to center align chip item inside autocomplete mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I want to center align the chip items inside an autocomplete Material UI
Sandobox: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiline-autocomplete-with-chips-forked-mm2zsm

I already tried to use a Box component, passing prop style=

```
   {{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        justifyItems: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        alignContent: "center",
        textAlign:"center"
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the DOM elements in the console, you'll see that your components are rendering like this:

```html
<div class="MuiInputBase-root">
  <div class="MuiChip-root">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="MuiChip-root">
    test1
  </div>
  <input class="MuiInputBase-input">
</div>
```

The two Chips are siblings of the input, and the input is designed to take up as much space as it can. So it's not actually possible to "center" the two Chips unless the input is hidden (which wouldn't make any sense), otherwise it's going to take up some amount of space.

That said, you can achieve a hacky version of your desired effect by applying `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to the `MuiInputBase-root` wrapper and then defining a `max-width` on the `MuiInputBase-input` so that flexbox knows how big it's going to be. The Chips won't be centered per se, because the input will always be sitting next to them. But you could bump that input to its own row so it would sit beneath the Chips, in which case they would be centered. Hope this helps!